# Making dictionary construction shorter in Python using defaultdict?

Tags: python

Is there anyway I can make this code-block shorter? It seems like something that could be written more efficiently:

```
combs = defaultdict(list)
for zf in zipfiles:
    chunks = zf.split('_')
    combs[chunks[0] + '_' + chunks[1]].append(zf)
```

Comment: `itertools.groupby` may help here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are searching for this:

```
combs = defaultdict(list)
for zf in zipfiles:
    combs["_".join(zip.split("_")[0:2]].append(zf)
```

Comment: A little bit cleaner :) nice